# I am getting error while training the ML model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, training-data

I'm trying to run the following code to train a model:

```
history = model.fit(train_ds, 
          steps_per_epoch=train_len/20,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          validation_steps=val_len/20,
          epochs=50,
          verbose=1,
          callbacks=[cp_callback]
          )
```

but getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert 0.8 to EagerTensor of dtype int64
```

I am unable to train a model.

Comment: What is the type of each feature columns in `train_ds`, for example if it is pandas dataframe then what is output of `train_ds.dtypes`?

Answer (score 0):

try to map steps_per_epoch and validation_steps using int function:

```
int(steps_per_epoch=train_len/20)
int(validation_steps=val_len/20)
```

Comment: same error occured.

Comment: share model class you created in the question